# Loading directly to windows

Tags: dual-boot

I'll start with that I'm fairly new to Linux, but I did briefly use Ubuntu once in the past when I was still on Win7.

My problem, Is I installed Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 but when I boot the pc I have no option to choose which OS to boot and boot directly to win10. I'm looking for a way to get back into Ubuntu, and find a way to choose between what OS to boot into when starting the PC. I already tried turning off fast boot both in windows, and the bios with no success. Any help is appreciated.

-Rob

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen this wiki article:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

When you install Windows it rewrites the MBR (Master Boot Record) with the Windows boot loader.  Following the procedure under "The Graphical Way" should get your grub back ;-)

Comment: Worked a charm. Thanks. I'm surprised that this wiki didn't turn up in the searching I did prior to asking this question. Either way, Grub is working, and i can now switch between OS installs.